# vs code typescript compile does nothing

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code to try it out. I hit Ctrl+Shift+B on a .ts file. The first time, it asked me to set up a build task, which I did. Now, I build again and it does nothing. I get no errors or warnings but no .js file either. An ideas what I missed?

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0", 
    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript 
    "command": "tsc",
    // The command is a shell script 
    "isShellCommand": true,
    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur. 
    "showOutput": "silent",
    // args is the program to compile. 
    "args": ["app.ts"],
    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems 
    // in the output. 
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "target" : "ESS",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you provide what your tsconfig and tasks.json files look like. You need to se these two files up correctly to get this to work correctly. Check this article for the right steps and config. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/04/30/using-typescript-in-visual-studio-code.aspx

Comment: I saw that article. I didn't have a tsconfig.json file. Is that required?

Comment: tasks.json:  
    `{
        "version": "0.1.0",

        // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
        "command": "tsc",

        // The command is a shell script
        "isShellCommand": true,

        // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
        "showOutput": "silent",

        // args is the program to compile.
        "args": ["app.ts"],

        // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
        // in the output.
        "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
    }`

Comment: tsconfig.json  `{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "target" : "ESS",
  "module":  "amd",
  "sourceMap": true
 }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have a problem with any task in Visual Studio Code, I change the output mode:

```
"showOutput": "always",
```

Now I'll get a window with the output, even if the problem matcher doesn't detect a problem. You'll see any problems here. Switch it back to "silent" when you have it all working.

Potential issues...

You currently have a target of `ESS`, I think you probably want `ES5` (note the five).

You should have got a count of `1` next to the warning triangle icon in the bottom left of the window for this.

Comment: thanks for fixing my formatting. I didn't figure out how to do that.  
I changed to ES5 which did fix the error I got from adding the tsconfig.json. However it doesn't build. I switched the output to "always". That revealed that tsc isn't found. I have VisualStudio also installed, so tsc is somewhere. I have to hook them up somehow, I guess. Time to do some more searching....

Comment: I went into the tsconfig.json and put the fully qualified path to tsc.exe instead of "tsc" and now it compiles.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hi Shaun - glad it helped - you can also update your PATH variable to include your `tsc` path, which will mean you won't have to use the full path everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run "npm install -g typescript"? See the comment in tasks.json